# React Native Listview Disable Recycling

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

This question may be a little unorthodox or go against some best practices, but I am wanting to turn of cell recycling in my react native listview.

I will explain my issue...

I am filtering 100 rows in react native. If I do not scroll after the 5 initial rows render (all rows have network images), my filter method works just fine. Performance is good with those 5. However, if I scroll and view 30 rows and change my datasource state, the listview will just re-use the cells and its horrible performance city for a few seconds. (aka things get choppy, my modal closing animation isn't fluid)

So I guess in short, I am wanting to completely reset the listview component when datasource changes or disable the recycling part. Is this possible?

**CODE**

Listview

```
        <ListView
           dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
           removeClippedSubviews={true}
           ref={'listview'}
           initialListSize={5}
           onEndReachedThreshold={1}
           scrollRenderAheadDistance={1}
           pageSize={1}
           enableEmptySections={true}
           renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
         />
```

renderItem

```
        return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor:"#ffffff",marginTop:1,overflow:'hidden'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.DirectoryDetail({title:item.title,item})}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flexDirection:'row',paddingLeft:5,}}>
            <View style={{alignItems:'flex-start',flex:3,}}>
              <Text style={{fontFamily:'oswald-bold',fontSize:screenWidth/15,color:"#000000"}}>{item.title}</Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                  <Text style={{paddingBottom:2,fontFamily:'oswald-regular',color:'#c0392b',paddingRight:10,fontSize:screenWidth/23}}>
                    {item.category}
                  </Text>
                  <StarRating
                    disabled={true}
                    maxStars={5}
                    rating={item.rate}
                    starColor={'#FFD700'}
                    emptyStarColor={'#bdc3c7'}
                    starSize={20}
                    selectedStar={(rating) => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
                  />
                </View>
              <Text>{newDescriptionString}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{alignItems:'flex-end',flex:2,paddingRight:5}}>
              <Image
                onLoad={() => this.setState({loading:false})}
                style={{width: screenWidth / 3,height: screenWidth / 3}}
                source={{uri: item.profile}}
                resizeMode={'contain'}>
              </Image>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
```

filter function that changes this.state.datasource

```
     //itemsString is my object that I stringify
     var itemsString = JSON.parse(this.state.itemsString);
     var all = itemsString.filter(function(d){
       return d.active === true
     })

  let newArray =  new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
        }).cloneWithRows(all)

    this.setState({
      dataSource: newArray
    });
```

Comment: Not familiar with native but I think if you change the key prop on the component you will get a new one.

Comment: Consider updating your question with your actual code. I am guessing you don't need to do what you're requesting and you actually have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I have included my code. @RobLynch, how do I change the key prop on the component?

Comment: Did you tried calling this.setState({dataSource: newArray}); within requestAnimationFrame function. also you should try calling this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows on filtering code instead of new  ListView.DataSource eveytime .